# Construction of irrational numbers

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, analysis, irrational-numbers

Can an irrational number be constructed which is a) not any known transcendental number b) not a surd?
If yes, then how can I construct one?
A detailed answer regarding the theory behind this and some references will be appreciated. 
 I modified the a) part to what it is now, because I am guessing numbers are either algebraic or not algebraic(I.e. transcendental). Is this correct?
I am thinking along the lines of constructing a sequence which converges to the desired number, but then  how to construct a sequence to a desired limit?

Comment: What is a known transcendental number BTW?

Comment: Err, e or pi or golden ratio?

Comment: What do you mean by a surd? If you mean something you can write down in terms of $n^{th}$ roots then the answer is yes. Some quintic polynomial should work.

Comment: @user286490 e and pi are transcendental and the golden ratio is a surd

Comment: Oh okay, and yes, by surd I mean what you.

Comment: Okay, I think the question can be reduced to "construction of transcendental numbers"

Comment: You are correct that numbers are either algebraic or transcendental (i.e. not algebraic)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes. If you know about Galois theory, you need an extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ that has a non-solvable Galois group (like $S_5$). If you don't know about Galois theory, then the roots of the polynomial $x^5-80x+5$ are irrational numbers but they are not surds and not transcendental.

Comment: Okay, but can I know what the number looks like?

Comment: Is it possible to prove that the roots are not surds without knowledge of Galois theory?

Comment: @cr001 I don't know of any way to show that the roots are not surds without using Galois theory. I think it would be quite difficult.

Comment: @user286490 what do you mean by what the number looks like? You could use a CAS or wolfram to get approximate complex roots of the equation. Another polynomial that will work is in [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_theory#A_non-solvable_quintic_example)

Comment: @Sam Weatherhog Thanks. But using Galois theory there is a way of proving numbers are not surds?

Comment: The problem with it not being a surd is that it is difficult to write the numbers precisely any other way. The best you can really do is to say they are roots of some polynomial.

Comment: @cr001 yes one of the major driving factors for the development of Galois theory was to answer this question. The Galois theory answer to it is that if the Galois group of the extension is solvable then the polynomial can be solved in terms of radicals (surds). See [this link re solvability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_theory#A_non-solvable_quintic_example)

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my comments.